# How can I initialize a IList<IList<string>>?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, matrix, initialization

Tried with :

```
IList<IList<string>> matrix = new List<new List<string>()>();
```

but I can't. How can I do it? I need a matrix of strings...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'd need:

```
IList<IList<string>> matrix = new List<IList<string>>();
```

but then you can *happen* to always add a `List<string>` for each element.

The reason this won't work:

```
// Invalid
IList<IList<string>> matrix = new List<List<string>>();
```

is that it would then be reasonable to write:

```
// string[] implements IList<string>
matrix.Add(new string[10]);
```

... but that would violate the fact that the list is *really* a `List<List<string>>` - it's got to contain `List<string>` values, not just *any* `IList<string>`... whereas my declaration at the top just creates a `List<IList<string>>`, so you could add a string array to it *without* breaking type safety.

Of course, you *could* change to use the concrete type in your declaration instead:

```
IList<List<string>> matrix = new List<List<string>>();
```

or even:

```
List<List<string>> matrix = new List<List<string>>();
```

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    IList<IList<string>> matrix = new List<IList<string>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work - you can't initialize a generic type parameter the way you tried:

```
IList<IList<string>> matrix = new List<IList<string>>();
```

Though, the inner `IList<string>` will be `null`. To initialize it you can do the following:

```
matrix.Add(new List<string>());
```

Answer (score 1):

if matrix is of constant size arrays are a better fit

```
string[][] matrix = new string[size];
matrix[0] = new string[5];
matrix[1] = new string[8];
matrix[2] = new string[7];
```

and if it is rectangular

```
string[,] matrix = new string[sizex,sizey];
```

Comment: I don't know initial size...should be dinamic :)